# Factor a template parameter pack operation

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, c++17

In the following template function definition, I write two times the relatively long expression `details::transform(std::forward<T>(t))` where `t` is a parameter pack.

How can I factor it?

`auto pack = details::transform(std::forward<T>(t))` of course doesn't work.

```
template<class ...T>
void f(T&&... t)
{
    auto check = (details::transform(std::forward<T>(t)) && ...);
    if (check == false) {
        return;
    }
    details::act(details::transform(std::forward<T>(t))...);
}
```

For tests purpose, here is a [complete program on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d551d120a77d73ab).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a sad truth to C++. Forwarding can become a cluster of tokens. And the more complex the expression that needs things forwarded, the more painful it can become.

Sadly, the only way I know to mitigate it, is with the preprocessor...

```
#define FWD(...) std::forward<decltype(__VA_ARGS__)>(__VA_ARGS__)
```

With that in hand, we can refactor your function to use an IILE to generate that pack only once:

```
template<class ...T>
void f(T&&... t)
{
    [](auto&&... pack) {
        auto check = (FWD(pack) && ...);
        if (check == false) {
            return;
        }
        details::act(FWD(pack)...);
    }(details::transform(FWD(t))...);
}
```

That way, you only call `transform` once per argument. I assume that's the net goal. Otherwise, you can probably use the preprocessor to generate something simpler without a lambda.

Comment: **IILE**: _immediately invoked lambda expressio_.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a macro.

```
#define FORWARD_TRANSFORM(type, var) details::transform(std::forward<type>(var))
```

Then your function becomes

```
template<class ...T>
void f(T&&... t)
{
    auto check = (FORWARD_TRANSFORM(T, t) && ...);
    if (check == false) {
        return;
    }
    details::act(FORWARD_TRANSFORM(T, t)...);
}
```

Comment: I mean, if you're going to use a macro, why not `#define expr details::transform(std::forward<T>(t));` :P

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. Your two variadic expressions expand to different patterns. The best you can do is something like this (without macros):

```
template<class ...T>
void f(T&&... t)
{
    using details::transform;
    // (T&&)t == std::forward<T>(t);

    auto check = (transform((T&&)t) && ...);
    if (check == false) {
        return;
    }
    details::act(transform((T&&)t)...);
}
```